# How to do imports in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, import

I'm trying to create a small Windows Forms application in PowerShell and I need to use some .NET classes. I have researched on how to do imports in PowerShell but I came across a bunch of keywords and I really don't understand what the differences are.

`Import-Module`
`Add-Type -Name`
`Add-Type -AssemblyName`
`using namespace`
`using assembly`
`using module`
`[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(...)`
`#Requires -Modules`
`#Requires -Assembly`

I have read, one thing to keep in mind is that some ways of doing imports in PowerShell only include functions and other import classes as well. `using` is supposed to make classes available, too. I assume that's the same for `Add-Type` because a class defines the type. But what's the difference between `Add-Type` and `using`then?

When do you use `Add-Type -AssemblyName` or `using assembly` rather then `Add-Type -Name` or `using namespace`? Is there a difference between `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms` and `Add-Type -Name System.Windows.Forms`? One refers to the assembly (the .dll file `System.Windows.Forms.dll`) and the other one refers to the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`. What's the difference between both methods?

Comment: "other import classes as well" <-- _PowerShell classes_ - not .NET types in general - `Add-Type` or `#Requires -Assembly` will make the containing public types available from a compiled assembly

Comment: I don't know what the difference between PowerShell classes and .NET types is. What about `using`? Is it the same as `Add-Type`? Also, is there actually a difference between saying "class" or "type" as in "`...` will make the containing types available"?

Comment: "types" is broader than "classes", but I'm using them interchangeably here. `using ...` directives are only required if you're writing your own custom class definitions in PowerShell (see the `about_Classes` help topic), but `using namespace System.Windows.Forms` might be helpful if you want to simplify type name literals used in your script (so you can do `[Form]::new()` instead of `[System.Windows.Forms.Form]::new()`)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that helps make it a little clearer to me!